# Generating a link to recover order using PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I'm looking to recover abandoned orders using a unique link sent to customers.

The link would include:

- Order ID
- Email Address
- Hash

All must be verified for the link to successfully retrieve the order.

The hash would a combination of a number of hashes, ids, email address, and timestamp - hashed using sha256.

Orders would only be retrievable for 14 days.

Due to all these details being required, I believe this should sufficiently secure the order.

Should I use this implementation or should I generated a unique identifier before sending the email?

Comment: Do customers have a login?

Comment: There is no customer login or any other way of identifying them

Comment: I generally lean toward over securing things so I would probably generate a random unique ID, that way even if someone was able to guess or figure out the details of their order they couldn't generate the link